# Using Runge-Kutta 4th order for a system of 5 ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, runge-kutta-methods

I'm an engineer and not quite familiar with solving systems of differential equations numerically, but I need to write a (fluid dynamics) program which contains a system of 4 implicit ODE's and an algebraic equation, which are:

$$
C_m \, \dfrac{dC_m}{dr} - \dfrac{C_\theta^2}{r} + C_f \, \dfrac{C^2 \, cos(\beta)}{b \, sin(\phi)} + \frac{1}{\rho} \, \dfrac{dp}{dr} = 0
$$
$$
C_m \, \dfrac{dC_\theta}{dr} + \dfrac{C_m \, C_\theta}{r} + C_f \, \dfrac{C^2 \, sin(\beta)}{b \, sin(\phi)} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\rho} \, \dfrac{dp}{dr} + \frac{1}{C_m} \, \dfrac{dC_m}{dr} + \frac{1}{r} = 0
$$
$$
\dfrac{dh}{dr} + \frac{1}{C_m} \, \dfrac{dC_m}{dr} + \frac{1}{C_\theta} \, \dfrac{dC_\theta}{dr} = 0
$$
and an algebraic function
$$
\rho = f(p, T) \;\;\; \text{(imported from real gas libraries)}
$$
I would like to use an explicit Runge-Kutta-Solver with C++, but therefore the equations must be explicit. I don't see how I could transfer these equations to a possible format, without having something like
$$
y_1' = f(x,y_1,y_2')
$$

I would be pleased if anybody could help me.

Regards
Clemens

Comment: Thanks for your response. It must be somehow possible to transfer these equations into explicit forms. This has been said in the relevant literature. But unfortunately they don't say how.

Comment: You have 4 ODEs, and 4 unknowns, so you should be able to solve them like a system of linear equations to get the derivatives separately. For example, you know $C_\theta'$ from (2), and you can work out $p'$ and $C_m'$ from (1) and (3), then (4) gives you $h'$.

Comment: Man, that was a piece of cake. Thank you! I would have marked your answer as the one which helped me.